# Microsoft Graph API randomly returns 403 - Forbidden

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a NodeJS app that has been successfully using the Microsoft Graph API beta for the past year to interact with Teams and Drive (mostly uploading files and posting messages to channels). Within the past two weeks, the Graph API has started returning 403 (Forbidden) responses about half of the time when requesting write operations to Drive or Teams endpoints. The app uses delegated permissions and the [resource-owner password credentials grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to acquire a token to make requests (Postman code example below):

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myHeaders.append("Host", "login.microsoftonline.com");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("client_id", "xxxxx");
urlencoded.append("scope", "user.read mail.read openid profile offline_access");
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "password");
urlencoded.append("username", "xxxx");
urlencoded.append("password", "xxxx");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", "xxxxx");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result.access_token))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

This will successfully return a token and list the granted permissions for the app:

```js
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "ChannelMessage.Send Chat.Read Chat.ReadWrite Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite.All Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read Member.Read.Hidden People.Read People.Read.All profile Sites.Read.All Sites.ReadWrite.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite openid email",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "xxx",
    "refresh_token": "xxx",
    "id_token": "xxx"
}
```

I can then take this token to make requests, such as the following, which will post a message to a Teams channel:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer xxxxx");

var raw = "{\n  body: { \n      content: '<h1>This is a test</h1><h3>More stuff here</h3>',\n   contentType: 'html'\n  }\n}";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/xxxxx/channels/xxxxx/messages", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Half the time this will work and half the time it fails with a `403` response:

```js
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-20T17:15:54",
            "request-id": "60e2a57a-6b44-4039-be4f-636debd10f87",
            "client-request-id": "60e2a57a-6b44-4039-be4f-636debd10f87"
        }
    }
}
```

In Graph Explorer, you can see that the needed permissions are granted, but the request still fails:

[image: Graph explorer error]

I have tried performing the operations in JS, the Java SDK, and in Postman, and I always run into the same problems. I have also tried both the beta and v1.0 APIs, with no noticeable difference. Is the issue related to my user authentication flow or my token session? Do I have conflicting or missing permissions in Azure AD? I'm stumped.

Comment: What is the user's role in this Teams? Is it a member or owner of this Teams? For a user who has no access to this Teams channel, he is not allowed to send messages in channel.

Comment: @AllenWu: The user account used is a member of every team in our organization. As I mentioned, this user has been able to successfully post to teams without issues until about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: It seems that this is not a universal problem. It may be related to your environment or the back-end O365 server. You can contact Azure support to provide the request-id for further investigation.

Comment: I haven't used Microsoft Graph API but--could it be a quota or rate limiting issue?

Comment: @stealththeninja If so, I guess it should be 429 error.

Comment: @AllenWu Our organization unfortunately does not have an account that qualifies for API support, so Microsoft has not been helpful when contacted. Also, it’s not a rate-limiting issue, since we can get the 403 on our very first request.

Comment: If you cannot contact the support team, it is difficult to troubleshoot the problem from the source. I can think of two points: 1. Change a user to call the request, and check if it is the user's problem. 2. Register a new Azure AD app, add only the minimum permissions required, and then try to call this request.

Comment: @woemler- Could you please check if user has Teams license assigned?

Comment: Does this -need- post as user (ROPC)? If not, there are other options of course (e.g. webhook). Just asking...

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT: the service user being used does have a license and is assigned the `Teams Service Administrator` role.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow: If all else fails, I could try going to webhook route, but this seems like a poor compromise, considering this API worked before. Can you create Drive folders and upload files with webhooks?

Comment: No, webhooks are purely messages into/out of Teams itself, but the other stuff you can do with Graph no problem, and the user is probably even less important in that context (who cares who created the folder, right?)

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow: I also receive 403 errors when creating/uploading-to folders, so this wouldn't solve my problem.

Comment: @AllenWu: I tried registering a new app in Azure AD, with bare-minimum permissions set, but I am still getting the same problem. All GET requests work, but POSTs only work about half the time.

Comment: Well, I'm suggesting changing away from the ROPC model - that might be giving the issue.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow: My understanding was that ROPC was the only way to generate a token for delegated privileges without manual user intervention. The app is questions is posting to Teams using a service account, and not the app user's account. What would another option be?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of ROPC - my question is whether you really need to act "on behalf of" a user. If you're using a "service" account anyway, then rather look to use Application credentials I think. The page you link to says it right upfront: "Microsoft recommends you do not use the ROPC flow." - I think it's meant more for exceptions than the "service account" type of approach. Conceptually, if you can change to Application permissions, I think the rest of the app code would remain much the same (e.g. the calls to Graph)

Comment: To post to Teams, you will have to keep using the user credentials. The doc for that endpoint says that the Application permissions aren't supported. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Some of the SDKs offer ways to get access on behalf of a user, here's the list of options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 2):

I would diagnose your problem with the following steps:

### 1. Check license

You probably already checked this, but are you sure your user (for the resource owner password flow) has a teams license assigned?

### 2. Check the token

I always use https://jwt.ms to inspect the token, go ahead and paste the token there (no worries, it's a Microsoft owned website that only parses the token locally)

Your access token should at least have the `ChannelMessage.Send` scope and possibly the `Group.ReadWrite.All` scope (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)).

The audience should be `https://graph.microsoft.com`

### 3. Fix token

If your token isn't correct, you should try to change the "give me an access token" request.

My suggestions:

- You aren't requesting a token with the correct scope(s), so I guess you should add the `ChannelMessage.Send` to the original request. Not sure, but I think it only gives you a token with the scopes requested even though you granted more access.
- You're requesting a token at the `organizations` endpoint, but for getting access tokens it might be that you need the tenant specific endpoint.

### 4. Try in the explorer

1. List teams `/v1.0/me/joinedteams`
2. Pick a team and list channels `/v1.0/teams/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/channels`
3. Pick a channel and send a message `POST` `/v1.0/teams/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/channels/{channelId}/messages`

```
{
    "body":{
        "content":"Hello channel, from graph explorer"
    }
}
```

Results in:
[image]

### 5. Open support request

On a public forum we cannot look into the specific problem, but if you followed the steps above, and you're sure the token is correct (you're getting the correct scopes and audience), but still get the forbidden error. You should create a support question at the azure portal. And provide them the body of the 403 error. They should be able to diagnose the problem by searching for the request-id.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, none of these steps helped resolve the issue. My token contains all of the required permissions, and I tried using both `organizations` and my tenant ID. Our organizations does not have a support account that includes Graph API and SDK support, so Microsoft has not been helpful.

Comment: I tested out all of the problem endpoints in Graph Explorer, with the same result. I have added an image of the error when trying to post to Teams above, showing that required permissions are granted, yet a 403 is still the output.

Comment: Can you check the token in jwt.ms and also post a screenshot of the result?

Comment: What portion of the decoded token are you interested in? I am not going to post the full result.

Comment: I'm interested in the decoded token on jwt.ms you can mask the user and the tenant id. Don't include the signature of the token!

Comment: You didn't specifically answer my question, but you gave the most helpful answer, so I am awarding you the bounty before it expires. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may have changed your API permissions after giving your application admin consent. When you give admin consent, Azure AD will take a "snapshot" of the permissions at the time of consent. Then if you change the permissions later, you will need to re-do the admin consent process again.

Try typing

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id={YOUR-APP-ID}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=%7BYOUR-APP-ID%7D)
into your browser window to prompt the admin consent for your application again. For more details refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin